# JSON (Gson) What is the best way to deserialize to a super class object and then cast to child class object

Tags: android, json, serialization, deserialization, gson

I am currently studying to use Gson for Json on Android, and I just met this problem. Assume that we have class as below:

```
    class Command {
        public int id = COMMAND_ID_UNSPECIFIED;
    }

    class CommandSpecific1 extends Command{
        public String specialStr;
        public CommandSpecific1 () {
            id = COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL1;
            specialStr= "special";
        }
    }
    class CommandSpecific2 extends Command{
        public int specialInt;
        public CommandSpecific2 () {
            id = COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL2;
            specialInt = 3.1415926;
        }
    }
```

I use the following code to create the Json string

```
CommandSpecific specialCmd = new CommandSpecific();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(specialCmd);
```

Now I want to do something like this (incorrect code)

```
Command genericCmd = gson.fromJson(json, Command.class)
if(genericCmd.id == COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL1) {
    CommandSpecific1 cmd1 = (CommandSpecific1)genericCmd;
    //do sth with cmd1.specialStr
} else if(genericCmd.id == COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL2) {
    CommandSpecific2 cmd2 = (CommandSpecific2)genericCmd;
    //do sth with cmd2.specialInt
}
```

The code does not work since gson.fromJson(json, Command.class) only creates the object for super class.
I know I can call fromJson with specifying the real class type, but is there any better way out of this?
Should I use customized deserializing method to fix this? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to deserialize like this ready-to-run example. As comments, you do not want to use the id field to switch between command, so you must trust field structure and assuming that for each subclass exist a combination of fields that uniquely identify your subclass.

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q20185625;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import com.google.gson.*;

public class Q20185625 {

   public static class Command {
      public int id = -1;
   }

   public static class CommandSpecific1 extends Command {
      public String specialStr;

      public CommandSpecific1() {
         id = 1;
         specialStr = "special";
      }
   }

   public static class CommandSpecific2 extends Command {
      public int specialInt;

      public CommandSpecific2() {
         id = 2;
         specialInt = 42;
      }
   }

   public static class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Command> {

      public Command deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

         if (json == null)
            return null;
         else {
            JsonElement e = json.getAsJsonObject().get("specialStr");
            if (e != null && e.isJsonPrimitive() && e.getAsString() instanceof String) {
               CommandSpecific1 c = new CommandSpecific1();
               c.specialStr = e.getAsString(); // do you need this?
               return c;
            }

            e = json.getAsJsonObject().get("specialInt");
            if (e != null && e.isJsonPrimitive() && e.getAsNumber() instanceof Number) {
               CommandSpecific2 c = new CommandSpecific2();
               c.specialInt = e.getAsInt(); // do you need this?
               return c;
            }
            return null; // or throw an IllegalArgumentException

         }

      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
      gb.registerTypeAdapter(Command.class, new CustomDeserializer());
      Gson customGson = gb.create();

      String jsonTest1 = "{\"specialStr\":\"AA\"}";
      String jsonTest2 = "{\"specialInt\":13}";
      String jsonTest3 = "{}";
      String jsonTest4 = "";

      System.out.println("Deserialize test 1: " + customGson.fromJson(jsonTest1, Command.class));
      System.out.println("Deserialize test 2: " + customGson.fromJson(jsonTest2, Command.class));
      System.out.println("Deserialize test 3: " + customGson.fromJson(jsonTest3, Command.class));
      System.out.println("Deserialize test 4: " + customGson.fromJson(jsonTest4, Command.class));

   }

}
```

And this is the result (I avoided toString, to show you the class types)

```
Deserialize test 1: stackoverflow.questions.qww.Q20185625$CommandSpecific1@30d5aa
Deserialize test 2: stackoverflow.questions.qww.Q20185625$CommandSpecific2@13552ed
Deserialize test 3: null
Deserialize test 4: null
```

**EDIT**
If your JSON, instead contains also the `id` field, it's more easy. You can always use a TypeAdapter, but in a straightforward way:

```
public static class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Command> {

      public Command deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

         if (json == null)
            return null;
         else {
            // null management can be improved
            int id = json.getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsInt();
            switch(id){
               case COMMAND_TYPE_1:
                  return context.deserialize(json, CommandSpecific1.class);
               case COMMAND_TYPE_2:
                  return context.deserialize(json, CommandSpecific2.class);
               default:
                  return null; 
            }
         }

      }

   }
```

However if you are interested in the rest of the JSON and you are worried about performances (but this is not the original question, you asked about a subclassing problem), you can try a `TypeAdapter`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting something new. Your answer is really different from those above. However, I did not say I don't want to switch the ID field. In stead, the best way I could image is to do something like this: STEP1. Deserialize the JSON only to peek the first ID field. STEP2. Deserialize the LEFT part of the JSON to get the correct object. It is something like in STEP1 we just consume the first 4 bytes (ID integer) and in STEP2 we consume the left bytes. I think this really make sense for big classes.

Answer (score 1):

[fromJson(String json, Class classOfT)](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)

From docs:

> This method deserializes the specified Json into an object of the
>   specified class. It is not suitable to use if the specified class is a
>   generic type since it will not have the generic type information
>   because of the Type Erasure feature of Java. Therefore, this method
>   should not be used if the desired type is a generic type. Note that
>   this method works fine if the any of the fields of the specified
>   object are generics, just the object itself should not be a generic
>   type.

So you have to use exact class while using fromJson method.

If you want to create a generic deserializing method you can implement something like below:

```
public Command deseralizeJson(String jsonString, Class targetClass) {
    return (Command)gson.fromJson(jsonString, targetClass);      
}
```

or more generic:

```
public Object deseralizeJson(String jsonString, Class targetClass) {
    return gson.fromJson(jsonString, targetClass);      
}
```

while using this method:

```
CommandSpecific1 cmd1 = (CommandSpecific1)deseralizeJson(json, CommandSpecific1.class);
```

or

```
CommandSpecific2 cmd2 = (CommandSpecific2)deseralizeJson(json, CommandSpecific2.class);
```

**EDIT:**
I understand your main problem now. You don't know the type of the json response before reading the value of id.

You can continue deserializing twice as you are doing now. (because GSON needs exact target class while deserializing )
Or use android's JSONObject. Such as;

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
// JsonString is converted to a JSONObject, it is much more efficient than gson serialization
int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
if(id == COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL1) {
    CommandSpecific1 cmd1 = (CommandSpecific1)deseralizeJson(json, CommandSpecific1.class);
    //do sth with cmd1.specialStr
} else if(id == COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL2) {
    CommandSpecific2 cmd2 = (CommandSpecific2)deseralizeJson(json, CommandSpecific2.class);
    //do sth with cmd2.specialInt
}
```

Comment: This still need to do deserialization twice. I want some customized method which allow me to do deserialization only once to peek the ID field and do static cast.

Comment: deserialization twice? No, json is deserialized to a java object once. then you cast it to a relevant class. Main point, gson needs the target class while deserializing(In your case CommandSpecific1 or CommandSpecific2). If you pass a super class of them then you only deserialize super class's properties.

Comment: According to my situation, I need to to do genericCmd = gson.fromJson(json, Command.class) to get a chance to peek the ID field and according to your advice, I should do another cmd1 = (CommandSpecific1)deseralizeJson(json, CommandSpecific1.class); to get the target object. Twice, Right?

Comment: Only CommandSpecific1 cmd1 = (CommandSpecific1)deseralizeJson(json, CommandSpecific1.class); is enough. CommandSpecific1 is subclass of Command and so it has property id.

Comment: Oh I see. If you want to continue with only gson, you have to deserialize twice(because you don't know the target class unless you read the id value.) you can use android's default JSONObject class for first parsing. see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Command genericCmd = gson.fromJson(json, Command.class)
if(genericCmd.id == COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL1) {
    CommandSpecific1 cmd1 = gson.fromJson(json, CommandSpecific1.class);
    //do sth with cmd1.specialStr
} else if(genericCmd.id == COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL2) {
    CommandSpecific2 cmd2 = gson.fromJson(json, CommandSpecific2.class);
    //do sth with cmd2.specialInt
}
```

Comment: This is what I did currently. But is there any better way other than calling the fromJson method again?

Comment: in that case, instead of 1st converting the json into Command object, use string comparison to check whether json string contains COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL1 or COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL2 and then accordingly convert it to Specific Command...

Comment: COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL1 and COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL2 is integer.

Comment: json that you are passing to fromJson method is string, so do something like this if (json.indexOf(new String(COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL1)) > -1) {CommandSpecific1 cmd1 = gson.fromJson(json, CommandSpecific1.class);}else if (json.indexOf(new String(COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL2)) > -1) {CommandSpecific2 cmd2 = gson.fromJson(json, CommandSpecific2.class);}

Comment: COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL1 and COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL2 is field value, it is const integer. It will not be present in the json.

Comment: if COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL1 and COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL2 are not present in json than your code Command genericCmd = gson.fromJson(json, Command.class)
if(genericCmd.id == COMMAND_ID_SPECIAL1) {...} will never work....do one thing just before if statement...write System.print.out("Json " + json); and see what is getting printed...