# Deserialize a JSON that changes internal nodes

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Server sends a JSON. The format is different.
For example:

```
{
    "firstName": "X",
    "lastName": "XXX",
    "address": {
        "street": "John Street, 10",
        "postalCode": "12311"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        "812 123-1234",
        "916 123-4567"
    ]
}
```

But the server can send another JSON

```
{
    "firstName": "X",
    "lastName": "XXX",
    "address": "John Street, 10",
    "postalCode": "101101",
    "phoneNumber": "812123-1234"
}
```

And my Format1.java

```
public class Format1 {
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    public String firstName;

    @SerializedName("lastName")
    public String lastName;

    @SerializedName("address")
    public Address address;

    public class Address {
        @SerializedName("street")
        public String street;

        @SerializedName("postalCode")
        public String postalCode;
    }

    @SerializedName("phoneNumbers")
    public String[] phoneNumbers;
}
```

And Format2.java

```
public class Format2 {
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    public String firstName;

    @SerializedName("lastName")
    public String lastName;

    @SerializedName("street")
    public String street;

    @SerializedName("postalCode")
    public String postalCode;

    @SerializedName("phoneNumber")
    public String phoneNumber;
}
```

The application does not know what answer will receive from the server.
How Gson can understand what class to use?

Comment: Did you write/ can you change the server side code that creates the JSON?

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution cannot be done. The code works and not will change :(

Comment: Well, since you know the structure of each JSON option. A (maybe not the best) solution is to interrogate the response as soon as you get it to discern its structure, i.e. if the value of the address tag is another json object or if the numbers tag is an array. Based on the result choose a class

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure in Format1 the member name is "phoneNumbers" while in Format2 it is "phoneNumber". You can play a trick to peek in the JSON string first to decide which type of format class you should use.

A more fair way to do so might be create your own deserializer method and check the name and type inside it.

Comment: The idea with the new deserializer method I like :) Can be an example?

Comment: This idea is from the answer to one of my questions, check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185625/json-gson-what-is-the-best-way-to-deserialize-to-a-super-class-object-and-then

Answer (score 1):

You could do as the link in the other answer (btw, probably Robin means *my answer* to his question :) ) doing like this:

```
 JsonParser j = new JsonParser();
 boolean test = j.parse(s1).getAsJsonObject().get("address").isJsonObject()
 if (test) 
   Format1 f1 = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Format1.class);
 else
   Format2 f2 =  gson.fromJson(jsonString, Format2.class);
```

but since `Format1` and `Format2` are almost the same, I suggest you to use only a class (I named it Card) and create your own deserializer for this class. I think it's more elegant as solution since you problem is have two different kind of JSON, not to different kind of object you manage. Here's the code you can copy&paste&run.

```
package stackoverflow.questions;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.*;

import stackoverflow.questions.q19715374.Error;

import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Q20254329 {

   public static class Address {
      private String street;
      private String postalCode;
      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Address [street=" + street + ", postalCode=" + postalCode + "]";
      }

   }

   public static class Card {
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
      private Address address;
      private List<String> phoneNumbers;
      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Card [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", address=" + address + ", phoneNumbers=" + phoneNumbers + "]";
      }



   }

   public static class CardDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Card> {

      public Card deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

          if (json == null)
              return null;
          else {
              Card c = new Card();
              JsonObject jo = json.getAsJsonObject();
              c.firstName = jo.get("firstName").getAsString();
              c.lastName = jo.get("lastName").getAsString();
              JsonElement ja = jo.get("address");

              if (jo.get("address").isJsonObject()){

                 c.address  = context.deserialize(ja, Address.class);
              } else {
                 c.address = new Address();
                 c.address.street = jo.get("address").getAsString();
                 c.address.postalCode = jo.get("postalCode").getAsString();
              }

              JsonElement jsonPhoneNumbers = jo.get("phoneNumbers");
              if (jsonPhoneNumbers != null){
                 Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
                 c.phoneNumbers = context.deserialize(jsonPhoneNumbers, listType);
              }

              JsonElement jsonPhoneNumber = jo.get("phoneNumber");
              if (jsonPhoneNumber != null){
                 c.phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>(); //java7 here
                 c.phoneNumbers.add(jsonPhoneNumber.getAsString());
              }
              return c;
          }

      }

  }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     String s1 = 
     " {                                           "+
     "    \"firstName\": \"X\",                    "+
     "    \"lastName\": \"XXX\",                   "+
     "    \"address\": {                           "+
     "        \"street\": \"John Street, 10\",     "+
     "        \"postalCode\": \"12311\"            "+
     "    },                                       "+
     "    \"phoneNumbers\": [                      "+
     "        \"812 123-1234\",                    "+
     "        \"916 123-4567\"                     "+
     "    ]                                        "+
     "}                                            ";


     String s2 = 
              "{                                      "+
              "    \"firstName\": \"X\",              "+
              "    \"lastName\": \"XXX\",             "+
              "    \"address\": \"John Street, 10\",  "+
              "    \"postalCode\": \"101101\",        "+
              "    \"phoneNumber\": \"812123-1234\"   "+
              "}                                      ";


     GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
     builder.registerTypeAdapter(Card.class, new CardDeserializer());

     Gson gson = builder.create();

     Card c1 = gson.fromJson(s1, Card.class);
     System.out.println("First json " + c1);

     Card c2 = gson.fromJson(s2, Card.class);
     System.out.print("Second json " + c2);

   }

}
```

This is my result:

```
First json Card [firstName=X, lastName=XXX, address=Address [street=John Street, 10, postalCode=12311], phoneNumbers=[812 123-1234, 916 123-4567]]
Second json Card [firstName=X, lastName=XXX, address=Address [street=John Street, 10, postalCode=101101], phoneNumbers=[812123-1234]]
```